# get File value from div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I have html file input

```
<input type="file"  id="file" />
```

and get file value then append it to  FormData() like that

```
        var formData=new FormData();
        formData.append("file",file.files[0]);
```

It works fine ,but I changed input file to dropzone.js div element like that

```
 <div  id="file" class="dropzone"></div>
```

How can I get file data from div and append it to FormData()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [events list](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-list) in the dropzone docs for more examples.

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#file");
//When a file is added to the list
myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    //Do whatever you want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellent article to get you started: [uploading files](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).
This is where I started :)

A sample from the article, to read file's meta-data:

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();

  var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.

  // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                '</li>');
  }
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}

function handleDragOver(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
}

// Setup the dnd listeners.
var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
<output id="list"></output>
```

You can also read the content of the file using the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), extending the previous sample for reading the actual file (also code from the same article):

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();

  var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.

  // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
      f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
      f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
      '</li>');
    // Only process image files.
    if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
      continue;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Closure to capture the file information.
    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
      return function(e) {
        // Render thumbnail.
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
          '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'
        ].join('');
        document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
      };
    })(f);

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
  }
  document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}

function handleDragOver(evt) {
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();
  evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
}

// Setup the dnd listeners.
var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```html
<div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
<output id="list"></output>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you, @MaxLeske for your comment. Added snippets relevant to the question